# Validation on a list using IF, AND and ISBLANK

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Im trying to validate my list in SharePoint 2010, so that it will only proceed when a column = xyz and a date column is not empty.

I took a stab at the syntax and came up with this.

```
=IF(AND([Status]='Closed',(NOT(ISBLANK([Actual Date of Acknowledgement])))
```

but it doesn't work.

Can somebody let me know how I can get this to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The usage of `IF` is wrong. `IF` is a conditional statement producting *either* one *or* another output based on its *three* arguments, like this:

```
=IF([Column1]=15, "Result 1", "Result 2")
```

What you are, most likely, looking for, is a simple formula as follows:

```
=AND([Status]='Closed', NOT(ISBLANK([Actual Date of Acknowledgement])))
```

See [this page in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx) for formula syntax and function reference.

Also not that in the formula you posted there are *five* opening parentheses but only *three* closing parentheses. That can't work from the syntax perspective alone.